# Have <input type="checkbox"> post 1 when clicked, 0 when not clicked

Tags: html

Is it possible to have a `<input type="checkbox">` post `1` when selected and `0` when not selected?

By default, it only POST's something (in Firefox 'on') if it has been selected, nothing when not selected.

Preferably without the use of JavaScript.

Comment: Why are you using a `select` for a boolean? Shouldn't you be using a `checkbox`?

Comment: Wow I'm dumb. I actually use a `<input type="checkbox">` in my code but wrote select.. Sorry, I will change the question.

Comment: The problem still is the same though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that in Ruby on Rails the default workaround is to use two inputs like so:

```
<input type="hidden"   name="whatever" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="whatever" value="1" />
```

That way, if the checkbox isn't checked, the zero value gets sent. But if it is, *both* values get sent. Rails will deal with this behind the scenes, but if you go this route with a different server backend, you may need to take that into account.

Alternatively, if you like JavaScript, you can use a nameless, valueless checkbox with its "onchange" event bound to something that sets the hidden input's value appropriately.

Hope that's useful!

Comment: Works great with PHP! Thanks :-)
Even though this is kind of hacky, it saved me alot of trouble.

Comment: @Williham - Care to clarify?  I'd be happy to correct any mistakes I've made, but I'm not aware of any...

Comment: @XavierHolt: I should be clear: I mean to say it's morally wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: No.

`<select>` only sends the `value` of the `<option>` or `<option>`s that is/are selected.

Just make sure you have an idea of what the options are going into it, and you'll have it made in the shade.

**Edit:** To address the updated question:

Same story still short: No.

Only the `value` (or occasionally content) of "successful" controls are sent.

If a checkbox is not checked, it's not successful, and as such, won't be sent.

Just make sure you have an idea of what the controls are going into it, and you'll have it made in the shade.

**Reedit:** It's probably possible with JavaScript, by messing with the `onSubmit` action, and setting the value of the related name to `0` if it's not already set.

At the risk of sounding like your tennis instructor, I *do* have to inform you that this course of action is neither wise nor advisable.

Comment: Note: the asker has radically changed the question; see the edit history.

Comment: @PeterO.: Thankfully, the answer hardly has to be changed at all. :)

Comment: @PeterO.: Also, he didn't actually radically alter the question. Form controls are all pretty much the same, when it comes right down to it.